# pycharm:Creat a new project and choose a interpreter with virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

There are 2 problems .
1.if I run a previous project, it would be error:can't open file xxx ：[Errno 2] No such file or directory. Actually, when I first run the file it was normal.
2. I want to creat a project, but I couldn't find the interpreter in the intalled directory of python 3.9. And I only have one choice, as this picture. [image]
The underline text  is the name of an  old preject. I really don't understand

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an PyCharm problem than a Python one.

I will try to answer these issues one by one:

1. `No such file or directory` means the path (the one you may have given it or the one it memorized) does not lead to your project anymore. Check that your path is still valid and leads to your project directory.
2. PyCharm uses `venv` (which stands for Virtual Environment) for managing dependencies and Python versions within projects. What is currently selected is the Python 3.7 interpreter within the virtual environment belonging to the project named "Coursera_Py4e". You can follow [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) to set a different interpreter.

Comment: The following description after 'Coursera_Py4e' is the path of Python 3.9. I want to creat a new project, if i choose the project named 'Coursera_Py4e' , is it a new project?